# Getting Fatal Error[Li001] in IAR Embedded Work Bench

Tags: iar

I have been loading my C project with a name `Start` but for some reasons I had to change its name to `Start_t`.

When I load the project with the name `Start_t`, I get a linker error:

```
Fatal Error[Li001]: could not open file "C:\Program Files\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 7.0\arm\Start\
```

It seems that IAR Workbench has kept the previous path.

Please help me to resolve this issue. I am using IAR ver 7.20.1.7307.

Comment: You really shouldn't create your projects under `C:\Program Files`. How did you change the project name?

Comment: I had just renamed the project name. `Start` to  `Start_t`

Comment: Yes, but **how** did you rename it? Did you rename the folder, or the project file, or the workspace file, or did you do something else? Workspace `.eww` and project `.ewp` are simple XML files; you could use text editor to search for `Start` and fix each path manually.